# Problem with logic when it comes to storing dictionary values in firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to re-create the instagram follower and following functionality but there seems to be an error in logic. There is no error in code. What I am doing right now when the "follow" button is pressed, is to create a collection called "user-following", add the "current UID" as "document ID" and then store the following target users data as [targetuid: 1]. At the same time, I create a collection called "user-followers", add the "Target UID" as "document ID" and then store the followers data as [currentuid:1]. The issue here is that it works when it comes to following just one user. When I try to follow another, the existing following user data gets overridden with the new user whom I just followed instead of appending the data.

Example: Assume currentUser is A, user1 = B, user2 = C
When I follow user1 and user2 my database in firestore should be reflected as:

```
user-following -> A -> [B:1,C:1]
user-followers -> B -> [A:1]
user-followers -> C -> [A:1]
```

The above translates to collection -> documentID -> dictionaryvalues
The problem is that I do not get the above result. Instead when I follow user2, the value of user1 gets overridden. So there is only one dictionary value stored.

I know that the problem lies somewhere in the way I am trying to create a field under the document ID. I know I can create a dictionary and append values but I think that's a lot of code for an otherwise simple solution.

```
func follow(){
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else 
         {return}
        guard let uid = uid else {return}
        self.isFollowed = true

        // Add followed user to current user-following structure
        Firestore.firestore().collection("user- 
         following").document(currentUid).setData([uid:1])

        // Add current user to followed user-follower structure
        Firestore.firestore().collection("user- 
         followers").document(uid).setData([currentUid:1])
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Realised that I had to use merge.

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("user- 
         following").document(currentUid).setData([uid:1], merge: true)
```